# retrieving all photos from database

Tags: php, html, laravel, image, photo

I am building a classified website and I am trying to set it up to show one photo from the database on the main page, that same photo on a category page, but when you view the full page of the item for sale I want to show all of the photos in that section.

Like how ebay shows one photo for the ad but when you click the ad it shows several photos.

I have used 'strtok' to show the single photo in my main page and category page but now I don't know how to setup the view page to show all the photos for that item.

here is how I am saving the images when the listing is posted.

```
public function postHobbies(Request $request){
$this->validate($request, [
'photos' => 'required',
'Photos.*' => 'image|mimes:jpg, png, jpeg, gif, aae, heif, svg|max:2048'
]);

$ads = new Listings;
$images = $request->file('photos');
$count = 0;
if($request->file('photos')){
foreach($images as $item){
if($count < 6){
$var = date_create();
$date = date_format($var, 'Ymd');
$imageName = $date.'_'.$item->getClientOriginalName();
$item->move(public_path().'/uploads/',$imageName);
$url = URL::to("/").'/uploads/'.$imageName;
$arr[] = $url;
$count++;
}
}
$image = implode(",", $arr);
$ads->photos = $image;
$ads->save();
return redirect('/')->with('info', 'Listing published successfully');
}
}
```

here is my controller for the page I am trying to post all of the photos on

```
public function view(Request $request, $id){
$ads = DB::table('listings')
->select ('listings.id', 'photos', 'description', 'year', 'make', 'model', 'price', 'city', 'state', 'email')
->where(['id' => $id])
->get();
$output = '';
if($ads->count() > 0){
return view('users.posted.postedads', ['id'=>$id, 'ads'=>$ads]);
}
}
}
```

And finally here is how I am currently passing it which is just showing me the single photo since I am still using the 'strtok' to make sure it works. So i assume i need to change this function i just don't know what to use or how to use it.

```
<div class="row">
@if(count($ads)>0)
@foreach($ads as $row)

<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="productCard">
<img style=" width:100%;height:100%; " src=<?php echo strtok($row->photos, ',')?> />
</div>
</div>
@endforeach
@else
@endif
```

Comment: Not seeing any code related to pulling from a database. Perhaps that code would be relevant to include in your question?

Comment: So do you want a loop to show all the images? just use foreach($row as $rows)

Comment: foreach ($row as $rows) just gave me the first image over and over. If i print the data though just in a heading like this <h3>${{$row->photos}}</h3> it shows me all 4 images in the database.

Comment: @GetSet I added some more code, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hard to answer without code but in your controller, put them all in an array and pass that to your view.

```
return view('...', compact('photo_urls');
```

Then in your blade.php you can simply loop over the array like this.

```
@foreach ($photo_urls as $key => $url)
 {{$url}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: I think i do have them in an array in my other controller if you take a look at the updated post maybe you could help me more. thanks

Comment: A very simple way to check what's in your array is doing this `<?php dd($photo_urls) ?>` in your blade file. This will give you all the values so you can check if everything is in the right order. You should use the compact() function in your controller if you want to pass an array to your view.

Answer (score 0):

As other's said. It is hard to answer without code.

But from your `strtok` function, I think that you have a field which contains all links to images.

You may use this code to get this problem solved.

```
$tok = strtok($row->photos, ',');

while ($tok !== false) {
    $output.= '<div class="col-md-3"><div style="text-align: center;">
            <img src=' . $tok . ' style="padding:10px !important;width:50%; height:50%;"/>
            </div></div>';
    $tok = strtok($row->photos, ',');
}
```

I don't know why you are not using `explode` function. It will become super easy then.

Comment: I think the explode function is what I want to use I just dont know how to do that? I have updated my post with more information that you might be able to help me with. thank you